# How to configure Notepad++ to open files in a single instance

Tags: notepad++

How to configure Notepad++ to open files in a single instance when double click a text file from Windows Explorer? I'm using version 6.6.8. Old versions always open files in one single instance. I need to open many files and don't want open many windows. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean multiple tabs in one window?

Comment: Preferences->Multi-instances->Default (mono-instance).

Comment: Yes, I want files are open in one single window with multiple tabs for switching among files.

Comment: I have used "NPP > Settings > Preferences > Multi-Instance = Default (mono-instance)" with no problem for years. However since a recent update, when I go in Windows Explorer (Windows 7 Pro), Right-Click a file and select "Edit in Notepad++", it SOMETIMES opens it in another instance, without notifying me of this unexpected decision, si I can't find my file, and if I redo opening it, I end up with 2 instances of the file in 2 NPP windows! Versailles, Tue 17 Oct 2017 13:23:20 +0200

Answer (score 0):

Create a totally empty file called 'asNotepad.xml' and put it in the Notepad++ directory at the same level as the notepad++.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

When I went into settings and looked under general I saw reduce checked. So I unchecked it and opened everything in a single window instead of only enough to fill the tabs in my window size and the rest in another window. I think a recent updated checked the reduce. Uncheck it and see if it helps.